# Why Android send input event from InputManagerService to Application by socket but not binder?

Tags: android, ipc

From reading Android source code, I get to know that when APP creates Activity/Window, in order to receive input events (key/touch) it will create sockpair and pass socket server to WindowManagerService, then registered to InputManagerService dispatcher. My question is why sockpair is used here, but not binder. Binder is the primary choice of Android IPC.

Comment: Probably not an answer, but this article https://baiqin-droid1001.medium.com/binder-file-descriptor-usages-b2b8a672873f claims that binder interface is not suitable for "streaming data" talking about Android's IMS as example.